# Elasticsearch on JBoss 6.4

Tags: jboss, elasticsearch

I would like to deploy elasticsearch as a .war library on my JBoss 6.4.

First of all, I packaged elasticsearch as a .war by the following guidelines: https://github.com/javanna/elasticsearch-war-example
Worked!

Deploying this .war file on my JBoss instance produces the following output:

```css
 Starting deployment of "elasticsearch-1.5.2.war" (runtime-name: "elasticsearch-1.5.2.war")
10:33:40,718 INFO  [org.jboss.web] Register web context: /elasticsearch-1.5.2
10:33:40,774 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/elasticsearch-1.5.2]]  Initializing elasticsearch Node 'node'
10:33:41,740 INFO  [org.elasticsearch.node]  [My Node Name] version[1.5.2], pid[21232], build[62ff986/2015-04-27T09:21:06Z]
10:33:41,740 INFO  [org.elasticsearch.node] [My Node Name] initializing ...
10:33:41,744 INFO  [org.elasticsearch.plugins]  [My Node Name] loaded [], sites []
10:33:42,830 INFO  [org.elasticsearch.node]  [My Node Name] initialized
10:33:42,830 INFO  [org.elasticsearch.node]  [My Node Name] starting ...
10:33:45,739 INFO  [org.elasticsearch.transport]  [My Node Name] bound_address {inet[/0.0.0.0:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/123.12.123.123:9300]}
10:33:45,750 INFO  [org.elasticsearch.discovery] [My Node Name] my-cluster/NILFFG5LRHyWIOk_X9hv4w
10:33:48,788 INFO  [org.elasticsearch.cluster.service] (elasticsearch[My Node Name][clusterService#updateTask][T#1]) [My Node Name] new_master [My Node Name][NILFFG5LRHyWIOk_X9hv4w][MYDOMAIN][inet[/123.12.123.123:9300]], reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
10:33:48,803 INFO  [org.elasticsearch.node] [My Node Name] started
10:33:48,831 INFO  [org.elasticsearch.gateway] (elasticsearch[My Node Name][clusterService#updateTask][T#1]) [My Node Name] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
10:33:48,859 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] : Deployed "elasticsearch-1.5.2.war" (runtime-name : "elasticsearch-1.5.2.war")
```

Obviously, there is no address bound on port 9200 to use elasticsearch's REST API, compared to a usual elasticsearch.bat installation.

- According to this "guide" http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/master/_deploying_in_jboss_eap6_module.html, I have to create a module.xml. Implicitly, I created the directory org.elasticsearch/main in my $JBOSS_HOME/modules, as the required module.xml as well
- I also copied the required jar's from my elasticsearch-1.5.2/lib to $JBOSS_HOME/modules/org/elasticsearch/main
- Of course I added any other module dependencies like org.apache.log4j to my modules folder

When adding my module as extension, I get the following error.

```css
[standalone@localhost:9999 /] /extension=org.elasticsearch:add()
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadException: Error loading module from C:\\jboss-eap-6.4\\modules\\org\\elasticsearch\\main\\module.xml",
    "rolled-back" => true
```

- Is there another missing dependency?
- Is there a more detailed "guide" how to configure elasticsearch on an application server, e.g. JBoss?

Answer (score 0):

For those who also want to deploy elasticsearch on JBoss, check out this thread on elasticsearch.com

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-deployment-on-jboss/304